# Is the Black Hole a very slow motion star explosion?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spacetime

Inside the black hole, in the event horizon, the time dilates, thats it : it stops! If the viewer is outside the event horizon, he/she will seeg something fall in the black hole and freeze(inside the event horizon)...
"Time is frozen inside the blak hole"...

This Happen Because the space fabric "fluke", where near infinite values are found.

So 1 second inside the black hole, is like 10 billion years outside it, *just guessing!

A black hole is like and explosion in very-slow-motion, the black-hole could explode with trillion and trillions of years or it could lose mass with hawking radiation...

The event horizon getting bigger (very massive ones) is just more junk being sucked and being freezed by time near the event horizon.

For someone who is inside the blackhole, feels being sucked and then would feel and explosion and die in seconds, and his/her atoms will be in space after trillions of years (like travelling too the future)...

Am i Right?

Comment: No, you are not right.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, just need a few clarifications:

You are right this is caused by GR time dilation. This is caused by stress-energy, not mass contrary to popular belief. Time dilation is caused by the difference between the stress energy (strong) of the black hole and the stress energy of empty space outside (weak).

To an outside observer, the clock close to the event horizon seems to tick slower, relatively, when compared to his own clock far away.

The observer's  clock far away seems to tick faster relatively (compared to the clock close to the event horizon).

The far away observer will see the infalling observer to close up to the event horizon, and then eventually freeze on it.

You are right, the far away observer will actually never see the infalling observer disappear, it will seem to be frozen on the event horizon.

The infalling observer will not even realize the event horizon, he will just pass it like nothing happened. The infalling observer will see its own clock tick normally, it is only when he tries to compare it to the far away observer's clock that he will see the far away observer's clock tick faster.

Now to compare a clock inside the event horizon to a clock outside could be tricky, because no information can leave the black hole (except Hawking radation).

But yes, theoretically, 1 sec inside the black hole could mean infinite time for the outside universe.

For someone being sucked into the black hole doesn't feel like anything strange if you disregard spaghettification. The clock seems to tick normally, as long as you do not compare it to another clock outside.